# How can I run the code the user enters into the Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor in a project, and I was wondering on how to run the code the user inputs into the editor. I was thinking I could use something like this:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chaos");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

function runProgram() {
    var code = editor.getValue();
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    try {
       var result = eval(code);
       display.innerHTML = result;
    } catch(e) {
        alert('Error' + e);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure about using `eval()` due to security. I was hoping to find some way to safely execute and display the users code. Please note that I'm a beginner in javascript.

Comment: You should use a backend language to send this code in POST Request and execute it in the back-end language using their functions and return the response of the execution. That is how it works. It is safer to do that way too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code written by user on the same users computer security is not a concern, since user could run the same code in the browser console.

But if you want to prevent the user from accidentally breaking the editor, you can use an iframe with sandbox attribute and appropriate CORS policies. If you load the iframe from a different domain, it will be running in a different process in chrome, and infinite loops will not block the editor.

A toy implementation of this would be

```js
iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe"))
iframe.sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts"

iframe.src="data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(`<script>
function runProgram(e) {
    console.log(e)
    var code = e.data;
    var display = document.body;
    try {
       var result = eval(code);
       display.innerHTML = result;
    } catch(e) {
        alert('Error' + e);
    }
}

window.onmessage = runProgram</script>
waiting...`)
```

And then when user presses run button use postMessage.

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(editor.getValue(), "*")
```

A real implementation would be much more complex see for example https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin for a popular open source project doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, This will be really helpful.